# How can I scroll to a certain component of the current page with routing and navigation?

Tags: angular

I am working on angular7 and making an app for learning purpose. I have 5 Components on my navigation bar. When I click on any of the links on the navbar, it opens the respective component. I only see just that component and all other components become hidden.
What I want, I need it to show the respective component on the same page with scrolling up or down. (As a single page application)

I hope I have explained my issue effectively. Can Anyone help me out?

This is my header component with nav bar:

```
<nav>
<ul>
   <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/home" routerLinkActive="active">Home</a>
   </li>
   <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/about" routerLinkActive="active" >About Us</a>
   </li>
   <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/faculty" routerLinkActive="active" >Faculty</a>
   </li>
   <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/students" routerLinkActive="active" >Students</a>
   </li>
   <li class="nav-item ">
      <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/contact" routerLinkActive="active" class="nav-link" >Contact</a>
   </li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

This is my app-routing.module.ts file :

```
const routes: Routes = [
{ path: '' , redirectTo:'/home', pathMatch:'full'},
{ path: 'home' , component: HomeComponent},
{ path: 'sectoin' , component: SectionComponent },
{ path: 'about' , component: AboutComponent },
{ path: 'students' , component: StudentsComponent },
{ path: 'faculty' , component: FacultyComponent },
{ path: 'contact' , component: ContactComponent },
];
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't use anchor tags and element id's?

Comment: in that case all your components should be under one parentcomponent

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the help.
Yes all of my components are under one parent component. All the components are under home components. 

I have used anchor tags in the nav bar. 
Can you help me regarding where to use id's.

Also let me know is there any problem with my routing. Have I put the paths correctly?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need `router` to achive this but plain old `javascript` should work.

Just use `scrollIntoView` to get the block into view.

Sample created at https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-scrollintoview-sample

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the help. Its good. But I also need it to route. 
I mean when I click any navbar item, it should scroll to that component and it shout also show the url of the respected component.

Answer (score 0):

Use anchor tags (ids) in your template like this:

```
<!-- ... -->
<li class="nav-item">
   <button class="nav-link" routerLink="/home" routerLinkActive="active" (click)="scrollTo('home')>Home</button>
</li>

<!-- ... -->

<h2 id="home>Welcome Home</h2>
```

...and define your `scrollTo()` function:

```
import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Content } from 'ionic-angular';

// ... export class MyClass {

  @ViewChild(Content) content: Content;

  // ... constructor() { ... }

  scrollTo(element:string): void {
    let yOffset = document.getElementById(element).offsetTop;
    this.content.scrollTo(0, yOffset, 1500)
  }

// ... }
```

Change 1500 miliseconds to adjust the speed

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the help. I really appreciate it.

Can you please help me regarding this;

@ViewChild(Content) content: Content;

what should i put in the place of "content". It is giving me error

Comment: Add this to you .ts file declarations. `import { Content } from 'ionic-angular';` I have updated the code snippet above to include this.